# Is there a third Carmichael number with only odd digits?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion, carmichael-numbers

Upto $2^{64}$ , there are two Carmichael numbers with only odd digits :

$$53711113=157\cdot 313\cdot 1093$$ and $$3559313513953=29\cdot 113\cdot 337\cdot 673\cdot 4789$$

In the first case, the prime factors give only one even digit (unfortunately, if they would also be all odd , this would be beautiful).

> Is there another such Carmichael number ? If yes, what is the third ?

I expect that there are only finite many such Carmichael-numbers. Do we have a chance to prove that ?

Comment: I was able to find one base-2 Fermat overpseudoprime, greater than 2^64 with this property: 391557355557595533797. And another base-3 superpseudoprime: 177335371997353711177. So there is a small chance that there may be a third such Carmichael number greater than 2^64.

Comment: @Trizen Great ! But was is an "overpseudoprime" and what a "superpseudoprime" ?

Comment: Overpseudoprimes to base 2 are given by the OEIS sequence A141232, while superpseudoprimes to base 3 are given by A328662. In general, overpseudoprimes are a subset of superpseudoprimes (and also a subset of strong pseudoprimes), while superpseudoprimes are a subset of regular pseudoprimes.