# Carmichael-numbers with only one odd digit

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, decimal-expansion, carmichael-numbers

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4736989/82961) I ask for a third Carmichael number with only odd digits in their decimal expansion. Far more Carmichael numbers seem to exist with the property that in the decimal expansion there is only one odd digit (one odd digit is forced since Carmichael-numbers are odd). The examples and their factorizations upto $10^{16}$ are :

```
gp > for(j=1,length(a),n=a[j];v=digits(n);w=select(m->Mod(m,2)==1,v);if(length(w)==1,print(n,"  ",component(factor(n),1)~)))
2465  [5, 17, 29]
2821  [7, 13, 31]
6601  [7, 23, 41]
488881  [37, 73, 181]
6840001  [7, 17, 229, 251]
6868261  [43, 211, 757]
40280065  [5, 7, 67, 89, 193]
40622401  [17, 43, 61, 911]
48628801  [13, 31, 67, 1801]
228842209  [337, 673, 1009]
662086041  [3, 89, 617, 4019]
6482062621  [199, 991, 32869]
22000404889  [23, 43, 137, 397, 409]
26244842401  [241, 3361, 32401]
84688680241  [11, 17, 31, 181, 80713]
284222862001  [13, 37, 229, 571, 4519]
422060284801  [73, 101, 107, 191, 2801]
422240040001  [13, 37, 41, 73, 241, 1217]
2240220288601  [19, 29, 71, 151, 601, 631]
2264864088241  [163, 181, 1171, 65557]
2442680604001  [11, 17, 73, 2731, 65521]
4440660840001  [19, 31, 379, 421, 47251]
8660646222481  [11, 17, 29, 43, 71, 631, 829]
24062884604641  [17, 71, 113, 211, 811, 1031]
26666686642681  [19, 31, 37, 61, 73, 109, 2521]
44026842848401  [7, 19, 433, 27109, 28201]
46462206204001  [7, 41, 61, 73, 241, 251, 601]
60086262020401  [19, 29, 43, 409, 1013, 6121]
86862448464001  [7, 23, 241, 1201, 1864001]
220440444666001  [7, 17, 79, 601, 3001, 13001]
286222824622801  [11, 31, 101, 523, 1741, 9127]
420040482684481  [19, 113, 281, 4987, 139609]
422422020044641  [17, 67, 421, 881, 991, 1009]
468842222066401  [41, 113, 223, 2551, 177889]
662064282864601  [31, 41, 71, 601, 1321, 9241]
688682280680641  [13, 31, 61, 241, 541, 214867]
808668068644801  [41, 61, 97, 113, 2341, 12601]
2044480642828801  [23, 151, 401, 17377, 84481]
2422860862020481  [211, 571, 577, 2593, 13441]
4226206884468801  [3, 17, 23, 41, 89, 449, 701, 3137]
4864046266648801  [19, 199, 281, 673, 2381, 2857]
8008686226464001  [13, 41, 59, 71, 337, 769, 13841]
8266200280884001  [127, 281, 337, 5279, 130201]
gp >
```

> Are there infinite many such Carmichael-numbers ?

Comment: There are $101$ examples of such numbers less than $2^{64}$. $48220840244846809$ is the only one between $10^{16}$ and $2^{64}$ that ends in a digit other than $1$.